# React Error: Getting error for using testData variable

Tags: reactjs

Here I'm trying to build a GitHub card app. But I couldn't able to use testdata variable in the cardList file. Later I will use API. But now I can't use it in the CardList.js file. Can anyone help me, please?

**Here is my MainPart.js file**

```
  import React from 'react';
import './Mainpart.css'


const Mainpart = (props) => {
    const testData = [
        {name: "Dan Abramov", avatar_url: "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/810438?v=4", company: "@facebook"},
  {name: "Sophie Alpert", avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6820?v=4", company: "Humu"},
      {name: "Sebastian Markbåge", avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/63648?v=4", company: "Facebook"},
];

     const profile = this.props;
    //  const userNameInput = React.createRef;
    //  const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
    //     event.preventDefault();
    //     console.log(this.userNameInput.current.value);
    // } 
    return (

       
        
        <div className="github-profile">
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Github username"  required/>
                <button className="add-btn">Add Card</button>
                
            </form>
            {/* <Button> Add Card</Button> */}
            <img src={profile.avatar_url} alt=""/>
        {/* </div> */}


        <div className="info">
        <div className="name">{profile.name}</div>
        <div className="company">{profile.company}</div>

        </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Mainpart;
```

**Here is CardList.js File**

```
import React from 'react';
import Mainpart from '../Mainpart/Mainpart';

const CardList = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Mainpart {...testData[0]}></Mainpart>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CardList;<Mainpart></Mainpart>
```

**Here is the app.js file**
everything imported

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Mainpart from './components/Mainpart/Mainpart';
import CardList from './components/CardList/CardList';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Header></Header>
     <CardList></CardList>  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Here is error**

```
Failed to compile
src\components\CardList\CardList.js
  Line 7:27:  'testData' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismiss
```

Comment: testData is defined in MainPart component then how can you access it inside CardList?

Comment: Tusar, Look at my solution I think it will make your work more easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. You defined `testData` at wrong file. You should keep that in `CardList.js`. And then iterate through testData and pass each item to `MainPart.js` to display on the card.

**CardList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Mainpart from '../Mainpart/Mainpart';

const CardList = (props) => {

const testData = [
    { name: "Dan Abramov", 
      avatar_url: "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/810438?v=4", 
      company: "@facebook"
    },
    { name: "Sophie Alpert", 
      avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/6820?v=4", 
      company: "Humu"
    },
    { name: "Sebastian Markbåge", 
      avatar_url: "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/63648?v=4", 
      company: "Facebook"
    },
];
       
return (
     <div>
        {
          testData.map(item => <Mainpart profile={item}></Mainpart>)
        }                    
     </div>
 )};
    
 export default CardList;
```

**MainPart.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Mainpart.css'


const Mainpart = ({profile}) => {                 
 
    return (                           
        <div className="github-profile">
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Github username"  required/>
                <button className="add-btn">Add Card</button>
                
            </form>
            {/* <Button> Add Card</Button> */}
            <img src={profile.avatar_url} alt=""/>
        {/* </div> */}


        <div className="info">
          <div className="name">{profile.name}</div>
          <div className="company">{profile.company}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
};

export default Mainpart;
```

Comment: src\components\CardList\CardList.js
  Line 14:32:  'item' is not defined

Comment: SyntaxError: T:\10.PluralSight\1.Getting started\github-cards-app\src\components\CardList\CardList.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (18:5)

  16 |             );
  17 |         }
> 18 |      </div>
     |      ^
  19 |     )
  20 | };
  21 |

Comment: Item issue is resolved. And don't copy paste the whole code. Please copy and paste only changed code into your code.

Comment: yeh.but profile picture and information is not showing. What to do?

Comment: Everything showing 3 times.There are 3 new add card box and button

Comment: So you don't want to show all 3 profiles which are there in testData?

Comment: Yeh I want show all 3 profiles with their information but there should be only one box with one button on top. but here is 3 form and 3 add card button

Comment: Yes for that you can remove add card button code from MainPart.js and add that in CardList.js  `<form action=""> <input type="text" placeholder="Github username"  required/> <button className="add-btn">Add Card</button></form>`

Comment: But profile picture and information  is not showing. what to do about that?

Comment: Are you receiving profile props `const Mainpart = ({profile}) => {` in MainPart.js file? And remember to delete this line from MainPart.js `const profile = this.props;` If you are doing all this then try console.log(profile) and check whether it is printing the profile data.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you call CardList component?
Did you pass test data to it?

**UPDATE:**
This should fix your error, instead of "props" use {testData}

- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyYoT.png)
- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc3Us.png)

Comment: I call it in app.js file

Comment: Please provide app.js file

Comment: import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Mainpart from './components/Mainpart/Mainpart';
import CardList from './components/CardList/CardList';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Header></Header>
     <CardList></CardList>  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: As you see, you didn't pass "testData" to the CardList component.
<CardList testData={testData}></CardList>

You need to move testData to app.js and pass it to the props.

Comment: I do it already but I'm still getting error

Comment: I added two pictures. It must work. I don;'t know why you add -1 when it's the correct answer.

Comment: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
Mainpart
T:/10.PluralSight/1.Getting started/github-cards-app/src/components/Mainpart/Mainpart.js:7
   4 | const Mainpart = (props) => {
   5 | 
   6 | 
>  7 |      const profile = this.props;
   8 |     //  const userNameInput = React.createRef;
   9 |     //  const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
  10 |     //     event.preventDefault();

Comment: I did't add -1. Someone did that

Comment: You can't use this.props in a functional component.
Set const profile = props.

Comment: Perfect. I don't know just why somebody set -1 on a working example. Somebody hates new contributor :D

Comment: Yeh that's true. There is a problem profile picture and profile information is not showing

Answer (score 0):

You are declared the variable on Main Part component. Only live in this component.
check the scope

Comment: can't I use it cardList component?

Comment: noup, the scope is incorrect. if you want to use it, you need to pass by any prop to Card list component.
I also saw, you are not using the component

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: You need to study web components in React (I think so) cuz you need understand the components. In your code, you are creating functional components, and I think are more complex to understand vs class components. Basically when you creat a component, you need to use the next way:
`MyComponent = (props) => {
return (<div>hola mundo {props.name}<div>)
}

<MyComponent name="Alan" />  // in this part you are using the component´
is just a basic example